# How to show that $Z(t)=e^{σ W(t)-\frac{1}{2}σ^2t}$ is a martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

How would I show that the stochastic process $Z(t)=e^{σ W(t)-\frac{1}{2}σ^2t}$
where $σ>0$ is a martingale?

I'm not sure how to do this, can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: There are at least two ways to prove this.

1) Show $\mathbf E[Z(t)|\mathcal F(s)]=\mathbf E\big[e^{σ (W(t)-W(s))-\frac{1}{2}σ^2(t-s)}Z(s)\big|W(s)\big]=Z(s), \,\forall s<t.$

To do this, ask yourself what the distribution function of $W(t)-W(s)$ is, then set up the appropriate integrate and compute.

2) Use Ito's lemma to show that the term involving $dt$ of $dZ(t)$ vanishes.

Comment: How would I pick the filtration?

Comment: The filtration is that of the Brownian motion $W(t)$. I have added more details to 1) to make it clear how to handle the filtration. If you like my answer, please accept it by tick the check mark.

Comment: I would recommend to use the second method, it is easier... although the first method is important to know.

Comment: @Hans Thank you, but do you think you could it solve for me as an example?  I'm just getting into stochastic processes, and I'm not really sure how to proceed, and I can't find any examples that are similar.

Comment: I added further hint for method 1). For Hint 2), have you tried applying Ito's lemma?

Answer (score 0):

You may apply Novikov's (Kazamaki's) condition on the adapted process $X_t = \sigma$.